# Sphinx: Exclude Next and Previous Buttons

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm looking to remove the `Next` and `Prev` button. From what I read from the doc, this can be achieved by excluding the `relations.html`; however I am not sure how would one go about achieving that.

I have tried to add the following to `conf.py`, without much change

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['localtoc.html', 'searchbox.html']}
```

If it is of any relevance, I am using ReadTheDocs theme.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using the *Read the Docs* theme for Sphinx, add this snippet to your `conf.py`:

```
html_theme_options = {
    'prev_next_buttons_location': None
}
```

Details at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx_rtd_theme/#configuration.